# jquery lightbox site gallery

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I am using this LightBox on http://nasltv.altervista.org/album1/galleria.html and just cannot get it to work. I have included all the files required, and more, including the LightBox plugin js files and its css file.

I believe I have the correct js for the page but it won't work correctly.

For those that don't want to click through the link to see the problem, basically when I click on the thumb image it just goes to the image instead of showing it in the lightbox. I'm sure it's a fairly simple problem, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the jquery for the light box in the footer of the page.
Also you can try this other lightbox that I use called Prettyphoto:

http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyPhoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/

Comment: I prefere Lightbox because  I can upload the images into the EXE program of this that creates the files for the site gallery. Other answers?